# Get Specific Version of IE

Tags: internet-explorer, testing, cross-browser

Anyone know of a way to get your hands on a specific version of IE?

Specifically, I am doing browser compatibility and originally developed for IE 6.0.3790.3959 (which most of our users have).  Some of our employees that have IE 6.0.2900.xpsp_sp3_gdr.080814-1236 are having issues with some of our custom Javascript animation effects.  I can find tools to compare IE 6, 7, 8, etc, but nowhere to get a specific build... any ideas?

EDIT: Yes, JS code used on the home page for an image slideshow, which is the centerpiece of our new design.

Comment: From JS code on the web page, or where?

Comment: I think he wants to download the specific build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Internet Explorer collection](http://finalbuilds.edskes.net/iecollection.htm) has IE 6.0.2800 and 6.0.2900. Other than that your out of luck.

Also, multipleIE and the Internet Explorer Collection will not run IE 5.5 or 6 on Vista. (IE < 5.5 works fine though)

Comment: Awesome! I was able to replicate the error in both 2800 and 2900...  big help, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, I don't believe the browsers supply their build versions when transmitting userAgent headers. The most you'll be able to get is MSIE/FF/Opera x.x

Comment: Good point, I checked in Google Analytics and Omniture SiteCatalyst.  I am interested in how many visitors have this build.

Answer (score 1):

Asking at the [Browser Archive](http://browsers.evolt.org/) would probably be your best lead. They don't have specific builds of IE for download, but the do have all the major releases of IE and service packs, so are probably the best people to guide you to a particular release.

Lots of other interesting browsers there too :-)

Comment: +1 for the good resource.  Unfortunately doesn't look like they have 6.0.2900.*.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this kb article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/969393/), IE 6.0.3790.3959 is Internet Explorer 6 SP2 for Windows Server 2003 SP1 and Windows XP x64, and IE 6.0.2900 is IE6 for Windows XP 32 bit (SP2 or SP3, I'm guessing your users have SP3 from the rest of the string) so it's not just the build, it's the OS it's running on. If you install IE6 on an XP 32bit box and updated to SP3, you should have a reasonable chance of ending out with a version of IE 6.0.2900 (but of course nothing is ever certain with IE except a world of pain..)

Answer (score 1):

If you already want this, here is the best site, here you can found all the versions of Internet Explorer since the first: http://www.oldversion.com/Internet-Explorer.html

I Hope I'm Helping You.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I could find.

http://www.microsoft.com/windows/ie/ie6/downloads/default.mspx